# Two servers, one domain, one certificate

Tags: ssl, web-server, apache-2.4, web-applications

There are two servers, one for web pages (Server A), one for web apps (Server B).

In Server A every web page has its own folder, domain and ssl certificate. 
In Server B every web app has its own folder.

Q1. Could be possible to setup the web page at domain_abc.com and their respective web app at app.domain_abc.com ?

Q2. If the above is possible it could work under the same ssl certificate ?

[image: View Image]

Comment: Yes, with a wildcard or multi-domain certificate.

Comment: could you lead me to solve Q1? I tried with an A record on DNS but can't include the directory where the web app is it

Comment: The answer to Q1 is still yes. Look up virtualhosts.

Comment: You can't include directories or other paths in DNS entries. You have to configure this in the webserver, using virtualhosts, as suggested. Most probably you want to configure Server A as a reverse proxy for the application servers.

Comment: I'm stuck with virtualhosts configuration, I forgot to say something really important, Server A and Server B are not in the same LAN, Server A is in a VPS in a hosting company, Server B is an EC2 (Amazon). Is still virtualhosts solution applicable?